# Renaming values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I do have a DataFrame like this:

```
col1  col 2
abc   sure
def   yes
ghi   no
jkl   no 
mno   sure
pqr   yes
stu   sure
```

My intention is to rename "sure" and "yes" into "confirm", so that the DataFrame looks like:

```
col1  col 2
abc   confirm
def   confirm
ghi   no
jkl   no 
mno   confirm
pqr   confirm
stu   confirm
```

How to do this :)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just:

```
df = df.replace(['yes','sure'],'confirm')
```

Answer (score 7):

Another method would be to use [`Series.map()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) mappings `'yes'` and `'sure'` to `'confirm'` and `'no'` to `'no'`. Example -

```
mapping = {'sure':'confirm','yes':'confirm','no':'no'}
df['col2'] = df['col2'].map(mapping)
```

Demo -

```
In [67]: df
Out[67]:
  col1  col2
0  abc  sure
1  def   yes
2  ghi    no
3  jkl    no
4  mno  sure
5  pqr   yes
6  stu  sure

In [68]: mapping = {'sure':'confirm','yes':'confirm','no':'no'}

In [69]: df['col2'] = df['col2'].map(mapping)

In [70]: df
Out[70]:
  col1     col2
0  abc  confirm
1  def  confirm
2  ghi       no
3  jkl       no
4  mno  confirm
5  pqr  confirm
6  stu  confirm
```